# How can I create a Macro to update some fields value in a web based application?

Tags: excel, vba, web-applications

Could you please help me in creating a macro? I am totally new to write any code. But currently I am working on a project where I have to do one repetitive task and it is bit irritating to do the same all the time. So, I want to create a Macro which will help me in doing the task easily. Here is what I do manually -

- Login into Application A using an URL
- Search for a particular order in 'Order' Menu
- Wait till the order failed, Copy the Order iD (different than the one we put in step2)
- Go to Another menu and search for the order id copied from above step
- select all the entry populated
- claim it, using a 'Claim' button
- click each entry and change some particular values to a value taken from another web based application (application B)
- repeat it for all the entries.

We use Chrome for opening both web based applications

Please suggest if there is any other way to do it. I don't want to use selenium for it.

Thank you so much

Comment: You already ruled out the obvious solution, so it's not clear what you're hoping for here.

Comment: Maybe try looking at how to update mySQL (or whatever the database that your web application uses) using VBA.

Comment: is selenium only option to create such kind of macro? I am not sure which tool to follow. I just want to create a basic macro which I will click and that will do my job.

Comment: the problem is more that you want to automate Chrome. You have fewer options when not using IE - AFAIK your main ones being UIAutomation and Selenium Basic